# If I call keys on a sorted-map, is the resulting seq guaranteed to be in sorted order?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, clojure, sortedmap

If I were to call [`keys`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys) on a [`sorted-map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map) type, I would assume the resulting `seq` would be in the same order as the key-value pairs in the map.

However, a user from ClojureDocs named [Jarzka](http://clojuredocs.org/u/Jarzka) had this to say about 2 years ago:

> I noticed that the keys are not always returned in the same order. Usually they are, but not always.

(Unfortunately I can't directly link to the comment.  It's at the bottom of the page describing [`keys`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys).)

Why might this be?  Should I `(sort (keys m))` just to be safe?

```
(def m (sorted-map :a 1, :b 2, :c 3))

(def maybe-unsorted-keys? (keys m))
(def sorted-keys (sort (keys m)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of keys and vals, it looks like a valid assumption that they will be returned in the same order, sorted:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentTreeMap.java#L888

Answer (score 0):

The docs [for `keys`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys) and [for `vals`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vals) read as follows:

- Returns a sequence of the map's keys, in the same order as (seq map).
- Returns a sequence of the map's values, in the same order as (seq map)

So whether or not a map is sorted, the results of calling `(keys m)` and `(vals m)` will correspond 1-to-1.  Since a sorted-map is sorted by keys, the result of `(keys srt-map)` will be sorted.